# How to initialise an inherited class in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, super

I'm having a hard time understanding how to initialize an inherited class in python OOP.

I cannot figure out what arguments need to be passed when I initialize it. These are the classes I'm using:

```
class BankAccount:  #parent class

    def __init__(self, owner, balance):
        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance

    def withdrawal(self, withdraw):
        if withdraw > self.balance:
            raise RuntimeError('Sorry, Insufficient Funds!')
        else:
            print('Withdrawal accepted.')
            self.balance -= withdraw
            show_balance = input('See account balance? enter y or n: ')
            if show_balance == 'y':
                print(self.balance)

    def deposit(self, amt):
        self.balance += amt
        print('Deposit Accepted')
        show_balance = input('See account balance? enter y or n: ')
        if show_balance == 'y':
            print(self.balance)


class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):        #child class

    minimum_balance = 100

    def __init__(self):
        BankAccount.__init__(self)

    def withdrawal(self, withdraw):
        if self.balance - withdraw < self.minimum_balance:
            print('Error, balance cannot go below minimum value: {}'.format(minimum_balance))
        else:
            self.balance -= withdraw
```

But when I try to initialize the child class:

```
acc2 = MinimumBalanceAccount('Milind', 1000)    # I am not sure what to pass as arguments here
```

Python gives me this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-85e55fb15340> in <module>
----> 1 acc2 = MinimumBalanceAccount('milind', 1000)

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

What do I pass in as the arguments?? What's going wrong?

Comment: u need to receive the arguments in the child class constructor as well and pass it to super class. without having the params in __init__ for MinimumBalanceAccount, you cannot pass it to BankAccount's __init__

Comment: `MinimumBalanceAccount.__init__` takes zero arguments, which is what you're seeing. You have three choices: Let `MinimumBalanceAccount` accept the same arguments as `BankAccount` and pass them through to it; let `MinimumBalanceAccount` accept no arguments but supply its own default arguments when calling `BankAccount.__init__`, let `MinimumBalanceAccount` not call `BankAccount.__init__` at all. Of those you probably want the first option. And since `MinimumBalanceAccount.__init__` doesn't appear to be doing anything, you can omit it entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the required arguments to the subclass, and to the superclass:

```
class BankAccount:

    def __init__(self, owner, balance):
        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance

    def withdrawal(self, withdraw):
        if withdraw > self.balance:
            raise RuntimeError('Sorry, Insufficient Funds!')
        else:
            print('Withdrawal accepted.')
            self.balance -= withdraw
            show_balance = input('See account balance? enter y or n: ')
            if show_balance == 'y':
                print(self.balance)

    def deposit(self, amt):
        self.balance += amt
        print('Deposit Accepted')
        show_balance = input('See account balance? enter y or n: ')
        if show_balance == 'y':
            print(self.balance)


class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):

    minimum_balance = 100

    def __init__(self, owner, balance):
        super().__init__(owner, balance)
        self.minimum_balance = MinimumBalanceAccount.minimum_balance

    def withdrawal(self, withdraw):
        if self.balance - withdraw < self.minimum_balance:
            print('Error, balance cannot go below minimum value: {}'.format(minimum_balance))
        else:
            self.balance -= withdraw

acc2 = MinimumBalanceAccount('Milind', 1000)
```

In this case, as pointed out by @Deceze in the comments, you can omit `__init__` entirely:

```
class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):        #child class

    minimum_balance = 100

    def withdrawal(self, withdraw):
        if self.balance - withdraw < self.minimum_balance:
            print('Error, balance cannot go below minimum value: {}'.format(minimum_balance))
        else:
            self.balance -= withdraw
```

Comment: Or you should omit `MinimumBalanceAccount.__init__` entirely…

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, thanks; I thought it would be a good idea to keep it as an illustration for the use of `super()`... I added the assignment of `minimum_balance` as an instance variable so `__init__` is needed

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the initializing parameters also to your child Class when you define the `__init__` function and pass it to the parent.

```
class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):        #child class

    minimum_balance = 100

    def __init__(self, owner, balance):
        BankAccount.__init__(self, owner, balance)
```

Comment: It should be noted that `__init__` here can be omitted entirely, since it doesn't do anything. If you keep it, you should use `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):        #child class

```
minimum_balance = 100

def __init__(self,owner, balance):
    BankAccount.__init__(self,owner,balance)

def withdrawal(self, withdraw):
    if self.balance - withdraw < self.minimum_balance:
        print('Error, balance cannot go below minimum value: {}'.format(minimum_balance))
    else:
        self.balance -= withdraw
```